# Spring Boot and unit testing of controllers, can I read the value of @RequestMapping at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, controller

In a Java Spring Boot application, I define the controllers path in a dedicated properties file. e.g.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/my.properties")
@RequestMapping("${controller1.path}")
public class Controller{

   @RequestMapping("/dosomething")
   public void doSomethingREST(){
   }

}
```

where `my.properties` looks like:

```
controller1.path=rest/path
```

The path of the REST service will be then `http://localhost:8080/rest/path/dosomething`

How can I read the path in the unit test class? 
Should I necessarily write it manually? 
Suppose that I change it, doesn't seem to be a very flexible approach.

Suggestions to make it more dynamic?

Comment: If it is a unit test then test the unit and simply call the method. If it is an integration test, then fix your test to match the URL. Externalizing them makes things only harder, you could put them in a static variable and use that to reference them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to unit-test the value of an annotation, unless you would use reflection - but in that case you would in fact have written a ["change detector"](http://googletesting.blogspot.nl/2015/01/testing-on-toilet-change-detector-tests.html), which is probably not what you want.

You could write an integration test however. The ["Testing"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) chapter from the Spring Boot Reference Guide provides an introduction how you could integration test your application.

Basically, the procedure is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SampleDataJpaApplication.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    int port;

    RestTemplate template = new TestRestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void testRequest() throws Exception {
        template.getForEntity("http://localhost:" + port + "/rest/path/dosomething", String.class);
        // Somehow verify that your application did the right thing, e.g. because some mocked component was called or the system is in a certain state.
    }
}
```